# Why does Photoshop CS6 is automatically re-opening the same file for months?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I don't use Photoshop a lot, and I don't understand why, but once upon a time I used it for editing a PSD file and since then, everytime i run Photoshop, it opens that file again.
I closed the file properly everytime before I quit Photoshop but once I run it again, it weirdly opens that same old PSD file for months ago.
I'd even like to delete this PSD from my disk, this way photoshop won't be able to open it at all !
But I wanted to try asking here before and see if that happens to somebody else.

Comment: How do you start photoshop? Is there any difference when using the run command (Start >Run> and type 'photoshop' ) ?